# What are these seemingly incorrect sentences called?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I sometimes stumble upon phrases such as

- This command not executed.
- This widget property of B.C.
- This page intentionally left blank.

The verb is missing here, isn't it? I see these types of sentence so much, and to my knowledge, they are just wrong. Is there a name for this type of sentence?

Also, why are they used? I mean, inserting an "is" in there is not that much effort, is it?

Comment: sentence fragment

Comment: Search this site for "headlinese".

Comment: "Headlinese" has a Wiki entry and looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In your two first examples, did you replace a name with "This command" and "This widget"? Or are the examples verbatim?

Comment: The verb in the third sentence is "left".

Comment: "This sentence no verb" is an intentional error, used to point out a mistake in a humorous way.

Comment: @MετάEd: Well, yeah, and the verb in the first sentence is “executed.” But of course the point is that *part* of the verb is missing.  (Actually, the third one could *almost* make sense as is: Jack Sprat left his wife, U left Q, and the page left blank (and not by accident!). But of course that’s not what it means; the page didn’t ***leave*** something; it ***was left***.)

Answer (score 18):

As far as I know (my grammatical knowledge is not extensive), these sentences are referred to as **[minor sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_(linguistics)#Major_and_minor_sentences)**. As Wikipedia states:

> A major sentence is a regular sentence; it has a subject and a predicate, e.g. "I have a ball.". In this sentence, one can change the persons, e.g. "We have a ball.". However, a minor sentence is an irregular type of sentence that does not contain a main clause, e.g. "Mary!", "Precisely so.", "Next Tuesday evening after it gets dark.".
>
> Other examples of minor sentences are headings (e.g. the heading of this entry), stereotyped expressions ("Hello!"), emotional expressions ("Wow!"), proverbs, etc. These can also include nominal sentences like "The more, the merrier".
>
> *These mostly omit a main verb for the sake of conciseness, but may also do so in order to intensify the meaning around the nouns.*

The final, italicised part of the quote should answer your second question of the purpose of these sentences.

Answer (score 6):

> "Computer grammar checkers often highlight incomplete sentences. If the context is clear from the rest of the paragraph, however, an incomplete sentence may be considered perfectly acceptable English."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Incomplete_sentence

These are good examples of when the meaning is clear despite the lack of a verb.

They work because they are terse and concise; the addition of a verb would make them less so.

Answer (score 4):

Everyone else has adequately explained what is going on and why and how this structure is used, but have gotten the name wrong.

These are called [Nominal Sentences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_sentence#Nominal_sentences_in_English):

> Nominal sentence is a linguistic term that refers to a nonverbal
>   sentence (i.e. a sentence without a finite verb). As a nominal
>   sentence does not have a verbal predicate, it may contain a nominal
>   predicate, an adjectival predicate, an adverbial predicate or even a
>   prepositional predicate.
>
> *(Wikipedia)*

The examples are in line with the ones in other answers:

> Nominal sentences in English are relatively uncommon, but may be found
>   in non-finite embedded clauses such as the one in, "I consider John
>   intelligent," where *to be* is omitted from *John to be intelligent*.
>
> They can also be found in newspaper headlines, such as "Jones Winner"
>   where the intended meaning is with the copular verb, "Jones is the
>   Winner".
>
> Other examples are proverbs ("More haste, less speed"); requests
>   ("Scalpel!"); and statements of existence ("Fire in the hole!"), which
>   are often warnings.
>
> A sentence such as "What a great day today!" is for example considered
>   nominal because it doesn't have a verb.
>
> *(Wikipedia)*

Comment: "I consider John intelligent" is an example of object complement, just like "I make John angry."

Comment: @AmI they are rather [predicatives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/predicative).

Comment: @moonwave99 - Delete the 'rather'.  Predicatives include subject and object complements.  "I consider John [to be] intelligent" has a 'predicative adjective over the object'.

Answer (score 2):

A rather specific (and to me quite annoying) situation in which this structure is used is in sponsor announcements on radio and TV.

It takes the form of a voice announcing

> "This program, brought to you by Joe Bloggs Yoghurt Farms."

I've always assumed that they use this form so the same announcement can be broadcast *after* the relevant item, as well as before it and during it.  If they included the verb, they'd either have to record two versions ("this program *is* brought to you" and "this program *was* brought to you"), or have a slightly awkward-sounding "*is* brought to you" after the item has just finished.

I think it's the cheapskatery that annoys me.

Answer (score 1):

Telegramese (or telegraphese).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/telegramese

Presumably it's because they were charged by the word.